# Are Dependency Injection and Mixins the same thing?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am trying to get accustomed to the ways of PHP 5.3 and I am confused. :o

Are they both accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are very different.  Dependency injection means "give me all of the objects I need to do my task."  A good counter-example would be a class that uses other singleton classes or has other hard-coded dependencies.

Mixins are essentially objects or classes that you can more or less merge with an existing object or class to provide its behavior to the consumer of that object.

Comment: Another example of the opposite of DI is every *new* somewhere in a class :) Additional (not mentioned by your neither by the questioneer) mixins dont exists in PHP.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Yes, good catch on `new`.  As for mixins, they can be simulated in PHP using the `__call` magic method.

Comment: Not natively, but in userland, there are implementations (example in Symfony framework, there is the sfMixer class)